# Different output by Write-Host and Write-Output to console by PowerShell

Tags: powershell, io

Below is a small PowerShell script.

```
function test() {
    $paramstring = "name=vindhya 
    id=182122"
    $hash_params = convertfrom-stringdata -stringdata $paramstring
    Write-Host $hash_params
    callee $hash_params
}


function callee() {
    param($hash_params)
    #$hash_params
}

test
```

Output is **System.Collections.Hashtable**.

But if [Write-Host](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849877.aspx) is replaced by [Write-Output](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx) then,

```
function test() {
    $paramstring="name=vindhya 
    id=182122"
    $hash_params = convertfrom-stringdata -stringdata $paramstring
    Write-Output $hash_params
    callee $hash_params
}


function callee() {
    param($hash_params)
    #$hash_params
}

test
```

Output is

```
Name                           Value

----                           -----

name                           vindhya

id                             182122
```

Why are Write-Host and Write-Output behaving differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Write-Output` will pass the output to the next step of the pipeline. If you are at the end of the pipeline, then it will output to the console.

`Write-Host` will output to the console. If the output target is an object, it will call the `toString()` method to convert the object to a string and then output it. Usually the string is the type name of the object.

You can add another cmdlet, [Out-String](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849952.aspx), in your code and then `Write-Host` would output similar content as `Write-Output`:

```
Write-Host ($hash_params | Out-String)
```

My test as below:

```
function test() {
    $paramstring = "name=vindhya
    id=18250"
    $hash_params = convertfrom-stringdata -stringdata $paramstring
    Write-Output $hash_params.toString()
    Write-Host ($hash_params | Out-String)
    callee $hash_params
}


function callee() {
    param($hash_params)
    #$hash_params
}

test
```

The output is:

```
System.Collections.Hashtable

Name        Value
----        ----
id          18250
name        vindhya
```

Answer (score 2):

Write-Object sends objects thru PowerShell's formatting engine. This involves checking if there is a formatdata file with formatting instructions for the object's type. The formatting file can choose various different default display formats: table, list, wide, etc. If there is no formatting data for the object, PowerShell uses other criteria like number of public properties to determine whether to use table view or list view. As a last resort, it will try to coerce to a string usually using the object's ToString() method.

Write-Host does none of this (except the last part about coercing to a string). It just displays the strings you provide it. If you provide something that isn't a string, it attempts a simple coercion to string and that is it. Often this results in just the type name of the object.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this with PowerShell. I believe writing objects is not usually well-accomplished using Write-Host - it appears better suited for strings. If you want to write objects, Write-Output is what you need to use.

[From the Powershell documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849921.aspx), Write-Output is used to "pipe objects through to the next command in the pipeline." Since there's no "next command", Write-Output is printing the object on the console.

Also, simply writing `$objName` appears to call Write-Output behind the scenes. Thus, if you wished to return your hashtable you'd do

```
function Foo {
    # Generate $hash_params
    $hash_params
    return
}
```

And this would pass `$hash_params` to whatever is calling `Foo`.

Comment: this answer answered my another question of why to use write-output if just writing a variable will do..

Comment: Thanks! Powershell is a bit daunting, especially if you're coming in from Bash; but its hooks into Windows can provide a ton of automation power.